# protractor, 'for' loop doesn't do actions for all of index

Tags: javascript, loops, protractor, element

I'm using Protractor to tests a web application, but when I use a for loop to navigate "remove" elements (buttons), it doesn't work properly.

Here my stepdefinition.js:

```
let remove = element.all(by.css('a[class="product__cta"]')); 
    remove.count().then(function(val){
        for(let i=0; i<val; i++){
            console.log('i is= ', i);
            browser.driver.sleep(1000);
            remove.get(i).click().perform;
            browser.driver.sleep(5000);
        }
    })
        browser.sleep(5000);
        let empty_title = element(by.css('.empty-title'));
        empty_title.getText().then(function(value){
            console.log('empty title: ', value);
        })
    expect(element(by.css('.empty-container')).isPresent()).to.eventually.be.true.and.notify(next);
```

In my console I can look at index 'i' and read the error message:

```
i is=  0
i is=  1
i is=  2
i is=  3
i is=  4
[10:09:13] E/launcher - Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 3, but there are only 2 elements that match locator By(css selector, a[class="product__cta"])
[10:09:13] E/launcher - NoSuchElementError: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 3, but there are only 2 elements that match locator By(css selector, a[class="product__cta"])
```

There are 5 'product__cta', not 2 as mentioned in the error message and the click on remove button works only for three of the five elements, in this order:

First el: Removed
Second el: Not clicked
Third el: Removed
Fourth el: Not Clicked
Fifth el: Removed

Why this kind of behavior? What can I do to take all the elements in for loop and to removes its?
Please don't tell me that there are only 2 elements that match locator By(css selector, a[class="product__cta"]) cause i'm still navigate the page and there are 5 of these elements.
PS: empty-container is shown only after the click on every single remove item.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try to  add `browser.sleep(10000);` before `remove.count().then(...`. Seems your code found 5 matched elements at page init open, but as long as page loading, the matched elements decreased to 2. So report index out of bound.  Need to wait page loading complete before count matched elements.

Answer (score 1):

You delete elements inside a loop. When you delete three elements, there are only two left. But you want to delete element with index 3, so you got an error. Just change this line

```
remove.get(i).click().perform;
```

to this:

```
remove.first().click().perform;
```